# What is the best way of writing this conditionality in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, conditional-statements

In My `rails` application, the users will enter a URL Which contains country name, like below.

example :

```
localhost:3000/usa

localhost:3000/uk

localhost:3000/canada
```

And my current logic in the Application is like this.

```
if ["usa","canada","uk"].include? (request.url.split("/").last)
 # some logic
end
```

Is there any better way of writing the above condition?

Comment: It depends on the use-case. What actually are you trying to achieve? Can there be scenarios like `localhost:3000/usa/some/more/paths`?

Comment: I just want the betterment or some different way of writing the above conditionality

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer define it in `config/routes.rb`

For example:

```
get "/countries/:name", to: "countries#show"
```

As a result you'll have `params[:name]` in the controller equal to country name from the route.

But if you have the exact list of countries, maybe you'll want to define a separate route for each of these.

```
get "/usa", to: "countries#usa"
get "/uk", to: "countries#uk"
get "/canada", to: "countries#canada"
```

Comment: My question is not about routing. i feel my routing logic is good. currently it was like this.  ['usa', "canada","uk"].each do |place|
       get place, to: 'home#index'
   end